# EntityManager giving a NullPointerException

Tags: xml, database, spring, jpa, entitymanager

im getting a null pointer exception while using the JPA entity manager

this is my DAO implementation

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {
    private Class<T> type;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager myEmf;

    public EntityManager getMyEmf() {
        return myEmf;
    }

    public void setMyEmf(EntityManager myEmf) {
        this.myEmf = myEmf;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        type = (Class<T>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public long count() {
        String entity = type.getSimpleName();
        final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer(
                "select count(ent) from " + entity + " ent");
        final Query query = this.myEmf.createQuery(queryString.toString());
        return (Long) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public T create(final T t) {
        System.out.println("Invoke the dao methode");
        System.out.println("Entity manage value : " + myEmf);
        myEmf.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void delete(final Object id) {
        myEmf.remove(myEmf.getReference(type, id));
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public T find(final Object id) {
        return myEmf.find(type, id);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public T update(final T t) {
        return myEmf.merge(t);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public List<T> getAll() {
        Query query = myEmf.createQuery("from " + type.getName());
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

and this is my dbContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="myEmf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.timeout">180</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_statement">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myshop" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="tracker123" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />    
</beans>
```

please help tell me what s wrong with this configuration

this is the exception that im getting while at the run time

```
    INFO: Server startup in 5017 ms
Jun 13, 2014 11:39:24 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{registrationUserBean.register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{registrationUserBean.register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1331)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:181)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kpowd.dao.basedao.GenericDaoImpl.create(GenericDaoImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.kpowd.service.impl.RegistrationBoImpl.registerUser(RegistrationBoImpl.java:22)
    at com.kpowd.controller.RegistrationUserBean.register(RegistrationUserBean.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions in startup?

Comment: stack trace to prove that the problem is happening when "using the JPA entity manager".

Comment: What other Spring configuration files are you using? (One problem that you definitely have that probably is not the cause of your issue is that you have multiple `<tx:annotation-driven>`)

Comment: im getting the null pointer while at the runtime

Comment: Remove the getter and setter for EntityManager since you are already injecting it onto a field/property.

Comment: removing the geters and setter have finally worked thanks mate

Comment: it worked but i want to know what i did wrong?

Comment: You can either inject it into a property or a field. But when you have both there and one does not have it, you will not have initialized it. This is not specific to JPA. I come from Java and .NET world and DI's usually have this requirement.

Comment: I believe that's not the case for Spring.  It is totally fine to inject to field directly, and with getter/setters available.  it is probably caused by some other reason